# How to create a many-to-many mapping table with exceptions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this database schema as shown in the image below:

[image]

It was fine until I need to change a few things.
So, some countries now have divisions within them. And each division may not have the same processes under them.

For ex, Germany has 3 divisions (Div1, Div2, Div3). And I have some processes applicable to all Germany, some are only applicable to Div1.

I am planning to create a new database, country_division, with the ff schema:

```
division_country
----------------
division_id
countrycode
division_name
```

But then I would there would be a conflict with my process_country table, when I need to add an entry to add a process to a country with divisions.

How do I redesign my database in such a way that it will be applicable to all countries?

Edit: Based on your comments, this is what I created. Please let me know if this will work.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me you need to create either a new table for division or a new column for divisions in the country table. Use the division_id as foreign key and link process_country with divion_id rather than country_code. Where country code is no longer primary key. division_id will be your primary and foreign key. If you need additional explanation let me know I could explain more in a solution

Comment: @Stivan I have edited my post, is that what you mean?

Comment: I misread your requirements. The second diagram on your post will work. I thought each process will only have one division linked to it. But if each process may have many divisions you need 4 tables like you have done. In the Process_Country_Division table you done need FK to Country code. It is already linked in the Division table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

On your diagram you don't need a link from `Process_Country_Division` to `Country` table. `Country` table is already linked in `Division` table.
Based on this diagram you can have multiple processes linked to multiple divisions.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head and without knowing all of your requirements, there are two options. You can either have all countries include at least one division (sort of a default division for those countries that don't actually have divisions) and then link your processes to divisions in all cases. This is the approach that I would normally lean towards.

The other option is to have your linking table include a `division_id`, but make it `NULL`able and have the FKs for division and country be separate. Then, for countries without divisions the processes under them in the link table would just have `NULL` values for `division_id` in that table.